# How to capture page event with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

Is there any way to capture page events with Selenium?
The application I am testing against handles error through popping up an error message box in the page. I would like to capture the event when error message box shows up to terminate the test as failed. 
I would not prefer a periodic check since I want to get the exact time of failure. 
I have read about ***EventFiringWebDriver*** and ***WebDriverEventListner***, but they don't seem to be the solution.
Is it possible? How to do that in Selenium?

Comment: is the error message box a windows popup or a browser one(modal, notification) ?

Comment: Is the execution hanging when the popup comes up?

Comment: The popup is a page element. It is triggered by either ajax response error or javascript error. It seems it's not blocking the other execution.